# How to check if a sprite object is visible?

Tags: ruby, graphics, sdl

I have a Array of Sprite classes with these methods: `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`. They are sorted based on his `z` property. The last are on top. I have, too, the screen size. How can I know if a specific Sprite are visible?

Comment: describe the ways a sprite can be invisible in your scenario and why you want to control it. Because it's completely behind (in z) another sprite(s)? because it's out of the screen boundaries? please expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to "make it work" is to render in reverse Z order. That is closest last.

Otherwise you have an N^2 problem of finding occlusion. You optimize this by building occlusion trees.

Another option might be depth testing the buffer.

```
class Sprite
  def occluded?(other)
    # check collision in X and Y
    # if they are colliding and self.z < other.z then self is partially or fully occluded
  end
end
```

Comment: If you render in that order, however, you have the problem of overdraw. By performing [z-culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering#Z-culling), drawing closest first, you can avoid drawing ones that are not fully visible. (But traditional z-culling uses per-pixel access, something possibly not available to the OP.)